# how count the number of rows in a dataframe with cell matching each other

Tags: r

I have two columns (one with **predicted** values (in strings) and one with **real** values (in strings) and my wish is to assess the number of rows in which the real values or string **do match** the predicted values or string **in the same row**.

[image: snapshot of the columns is shown in the link]

I was wondering whether it is possible to something like that with R?

Comment: Please include a subset of your data (or all of it) using `dput` so we can reproduce it on our own machines, the error you are getting, and the output you are wishing to see. Otherwise people will vote down your question. Thanks :)

Comment: Please always post text from data, code, error messages directly on SO, [not as a picture.](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Comment: @mysteRious ah sorry, I didn't know there was a option available to upload data on stackoverflow,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# create sample dataset
df <- data.frame(
    col1 = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"),
    col2 = c("a", "x", "y", "z", "e"),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

# count the number of rows where two columns equal each other
sum( df$col1 == df$col2 )
```

Comment: @Joy: there are still sum nuisances, for example if you have any `NA` values the sum function returns `NA` unless you add `na.rm=TRUE` as one of its arguments.